# Find in first array values and then change them with values from another array

Tags: javascript

First array

```
var danu = ["nu", "da", "nu", "da", "da", "da", "da", "da", "da", "nu", "nu"];
```

Second array

```
var abc2 = ["2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2"];
```

I want to replace all "da" from first array with the values from the second array 1 by 1 so i will get

```
["nu", "2", "nu", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "nu", "nu"];
```

I want the fix only in Javascript. 
I tried using the loop metod

```
for (i=0; i<danu.length; i++) {
if (danu[i] == "da") {
 danu[i] = abc2[i];
}
}
```

But i end up getting the array to this

```
["nu", "3", "nu", "3", "3", "2", "2", undefined, undefined, "nu", "nu"]
```

Comment: So loop through and replace with the second...

Comment: I tried looping through but i don't know exactly how should i do to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here. Hint: Use a for loop or some of the array prototype methods

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: if ( value equals ) Replace value with first value from other array, increment  counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map` to apply changes on each item in the `danu` array. Then have a `c` count which increments when `"da"` was found.

```
danu = ["nu", "da", "nu", "da", "da", "da", "da", "da", "da", "nu", "nu"];
abc2 = ["2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2"];

c = 0;

newArr = danu.map(function(e,i){
    if(e == 'da') return abc2[c++];
    return e;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Could you not start at 0 and `return abc2[c++];` ?

Comment: @mplungjan That's a good point, I've added that into my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @mplungjan For the second method you will want to use `shift` rather than pop. http://jsfiddle.net/90jgjekd/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var danu = ["nu", "da", "nu", "da", "da", "da", "da", "da", "da", "nu", "nu"],
    abc2 = ["2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2"];
  
danu.reduce(function (r, a, i, o) {
    o[i] = a === 'da' ? abc2[r++] : a;
    return r;
}, 0);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(danu, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: @mplungjan, yes, map is shorter for a new array, but this solution works in situ.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the second array is equal in length to the number of "da" in the first array, the code would look like:

```
var j = 0;
for(int i; i<danu.length; i++){
    if(danu[i] === "da"){
        danu[i] = abc2[j];
        j = j + 1;
    }
}
```

However, if the second array is of different length, incrementing j could put abc2 out of bounds. You would need a different strategy based on what you are actually trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work. I get unexpected identifier error...but thanks anyway, i got the fix from previous answer.